# Inserting strings at changing positions

Tags: c#, string, token

I've stumbled and I need some help.

I need a way of inserting substrings into a longer string, based on an index.
Unfortunately, subsequent inserts make the original indices obsolete (as the string becomes longer), and I wonder if there's some way around this?

```
This is a hyperlink. And so is this.
          ^-------^            ^--^
         10      19           31  35
```

After first insertion, the second index will change:

```
This is a <a href="#">hyperlink. And so is this.
                                           ^--^
                              31          43  47
```

Does anyone know of a method/library/algorithm to achieve what I want?

So that I magically can insert, but still use the **original indices**?

Comment: `old index + inserted section length`?

Comment: @Ian Sure, but I have a list of indices and substrings, how do I do this in pseudo code? Each subsequent index needs to update?

Comment: Start replacing from the end

Comment: @JamesThorpe Hmmm... Could you post some code on your methodology?

Comment: @silkfire Uhhh, no.  I'm not a code writing service.  You say you _"have a list of indices and substrings"_, presumably you're iterating through it - just do that backwards.

Comment: Since you didn't post any code I cannot be sure how you're inserting into your `string`, but if you are using `string.Insert` to create a new `string` on each insertion I'd recommend you look at using a `StringBuilder` instead, especially if you have to do a lot of insertions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace from the highest indices to the lowest. Only the indices *after* what you're replacing change, so if you start from the highest, you can keep the same indices and everything will be replaced correctly, no adjustments needed. If you only need a single pass through the string, this is an extremely simple solution :)

```
This is a hyperlink. And so is this.
          ^-------^            ^--^
         10      19           31  35

This is a hyperlink. And so is My new hyperlink this.
          ^-------^            ^-------------------^
         10      19           31

This is a another hyperlink. And so is My new hyperlink this.
          ^---------------^            ^-------------------^
         10
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem; what works for you depends a bit on what you are doing in the first place. For example:

- If you do some kind of searching to find those indexes, then a good way to solve this is by performing the search iteratively. Instead of finding all indexes at once before any replacements, you would search for the first, perform the replacement and then search from there for the next item. For example a simple `String.IndexOf()` works well for that.
- If you have actual replacements to make, you can just leave the job of handling those indexes to the regular expression library. So you would just do a `RegExp.Replace()` and it would automatically work without you having to do anything with indexes. If you need to perform more complicated replacements, you can also use a [match evaluator delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) to run code for each replacement. Again, you don’t need to manually adjust the string in that case.
- If you just have indexes for which you need to make replacements, a common example would be URL entities returned by the Twitter API (since Twitter tells you where a link is, and where you need to make a replacement), then you can do this by splitting the string up. Basically, if you have replacement ranges `[10, 19]` and `[31, 35]`, then you would split the string into three parts: `[0, 9]`, `[19, 30]` and `[35, …]`. And then you just put your replacements between them and join it together to get the result string.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to generalise. If you have a longer string just have a variable that you increment with the length of each addition .

So if you have this list

```
Idices  - Substrings

1  -  "test" 
10 -  "link"
30 - "another test"
```

and the variable  `int indexSum = 0` which you increment at every insert like `indexSum += substring.Length;` 
When you want to insert at index 10 you will actually insert 10 + indexSum and indexSum will be `indexSum+4`

Comment: You also need to take care only to increment indices that are *after* your inserted text.  If the index is before the insertion the index won't change.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Luaan's answer makes more sense. Unless you can't order the list that way, use their answer.

In some structured English:

```
Order the substrings to be inserted by the index
Insert the first substring
Increment the index of the rest of the substrings by the length of the first substring
Repeat
```

Or you could keep a variable that records the length of all inserted text. This would probably be more efficient.

Just add this variable to the index of the substring being inserted and then increment the variable by the length of the substring